# Return value must be of type Collections array returned Doctrine / Symfony 6

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have 2 order and line entities, with onetoMany / manytoOne relationship

I want to save a command with its lines, except I need to customize things, so I go through a datapersister function persist

If I don't try to save my lines it goes well, but as soon as I want to save the lines I get this message:

"App\Entity\DoRetourEntete::getRetALignes(): the return value must be of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, array returned

Basically I'm sending it an array while it's waiting for a collection.

But how to send it a collection in json?

In get everything works fine, I have my line detail when I call a command.

Here is my POST:

```
{
  "nomCommande": "2398",
  "cmdALignes": [
    {
      "ref": "maref1",
      "des1": "designation1",
      "qtt": 2
    },
    {
      "ref": "maref2",
      "des1": "designation2",
      "qtt": 2
    }
 
    
  ]
}
```

Here is a piece of my entities:

Commande:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=lignes::class, mappedBy="ligneEntete")
     */
    private $cmdALignes;
 
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cmdALignes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
 
    /**
     * @return Collection|Post[]
     */
    public function getCmdALignes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->cmdALignes;
    }
 
    public function setCmdALignes(array $cmdALignes): self
    {
        $this->cmdALignes= $cmdALignes;
 
        return $this;
    }
```

and ligne :

```
/**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Commande::class, inversedBy="cmdALignes")<br>
     */
    private $ligneEntete;
 
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ligneEntete= new ArrayCollection();<br>    }
 
    public function getLigneEntete(): ?Commande
    {
        return $this->ligneEntete;<br>    }
 
 
    public function setLigneEntete(?Commande $ligneEntete): self
    {
        $this->ligneEntete= $ligneEntete;
        return $this;
    }
```

In my data persister :

```
$commande = new Commande();
$commande->setNomCommande($data->getNomCommande);
```

and in principle if I want to browse my lines, I do:

```
foreach ($data->getCmdALignes() as $ligne){ }
```

I know that I send an array in a collection but how to do?
thanks in advance

Guillaume

Comment: You ask an array in your setter, and return a collection in the getter. Have you tried setting "array" as return type for getCmdALignes() ? Or the other way around, but you'd need to ensure you send a collection in the hydrator

Comment: thank, 
if I pass my get in array, my POST works, but my GET no longer works : Return value must be of type array, Doctrine\\ORM\\PersistentCollection returned

Comment: PersistentCollection has a "toArray()" method you could call it in your getter. I'm not saying it's the right way to do it, i don't know how symfony handles the hydration process

Answer (score 0):

Collection and array are not the same thing. A collection is a class that is iterable and has methods for adding, removing, counting, etc.

Change

this

```php
public function setCmdALignes(array $cmdALignes): self
    {
        $this->cmdALignes= $cmdALignes;

        return $this;
    }
```

to this

```php
public function setCmdALignes(array $cmdALignes): self
    { 
        foreach ($cmdALignes as $cmdALigne){
             $this->cmdALignes->add($cmdALigne);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

or this

```php
public function setCmdALignes(array $cmdALignes): self
    { 
        $this->cmdALignes = new ArrayCollection($cmdALignes);

        return $this;
    }
```

I recommend reading the article
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/stable/index.html